# Ajax generated content and jquery event binding

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page that displays products. The products are displayed via a ajax request. Included with the products are the pagination buttons. Here is my 
    $('document').ready(function(){

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url().'catalog/show_listings';?>',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                    $('#result_container').html(data);
                }, // End of success function of ajax form
             complete : function(){
                    $('ul#pag-link > li > a').click(function(){

                        var link = $(this).attr('href')

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<?=base_url().'catalog/show_listings';?>',
                            type:'GET',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(listings){
                                    $('#result_container').html(listings);
                                } // End of success function of ajax form       
                         }); // End of ajax call                            

                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }); // End of ajax call
```

On success of the first ajax call I  get the listings and displays them in div #result_container. Then on complete of that same ajax call I create a on click for the anchors in the unordered list #pag-
link (the pagination buttons). This should return the next set of listings and again display it in #result_container, it will also again load the pagination buttons. I do this on complete because I cant do it earlier, as the pagination buttons are not present on binding.

Here is the problem, to make it work I would have to again in the ajax complete add the onclick event for the pagination buttons. I will have to do this for every ajax load of more products and the pagination.

THis is obviously not the right approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: btw, you are not using the `link` variable you create..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate the event handling to the container elements that is always there..

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url().'catalog/show_listings';?>',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $('#result_container').html(data);
    } // End of success function of ajax form
}); // End of ajax call

$('#result_container').on('click', '#pag-link > li > a', function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?=base_url().'catalog/show_listings';?>',
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(listings){
            $('#result_container').html(listings);
        } // End of success function of ajax form       
    }); // End of ajax call                            

    return false;
});
```

and run this on dom ready (*outside of all ajax calls*)

---

(*also if the two calls are identical, you could create a function and use that to avoid duplicate code..*)

Comment: Thanks! When my plans come to fruition and I rule the world, statues will be erected in your honor and all men, woman and children will know of Gaby the Wise and Generous.